# Managing two ssh keys

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-keys, linux-mint

I have multiple SSH keys on a single device.

```
// example
id_rsa_github_office.pub , id_rsa_github_personal.pub
```

**How can I manage multiple SSH keys without conflict on a single device?**

Comment: Please be more specific about what you want. If you just want to "use both keys in one pc", why don't you just copy over the two `id_rsa*` files and store them under different names? The name is arbitrary. On the ssh command line you can specify an `-i identity_file` option to select between the two keys. Also in the `~/.ssh/config` you can configure to use one key for one ssh connection and the other for a second (or all other) ssh connection(s). If you search for these keywords, there's ample documentation on this on the net.

Answer (score 4):

#### Create a SSH config file

> When you have multiple identity files, create a SSH config file mechanisms to create aliases for your various identities.
>
> You can construct a SSH config file using many parameters and different approaches.
>
> The format for the alias entries use in this example is:
>
> ```
> Host alias 
>   HostName bitbucket.org 
>   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
> ```
>
> To create a config file for two identities (workid and personalid), you would do the following:

```
Open a terminal window.
Edit the ~/.ssh/config file.
```

If you don't have a config file, create one.
Add an alias for each identity combination for example:

```
Host workid
HostName bitbucket.org
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/workid

Host personalid
HostName bitbucket.org
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personalid
```

## PS

Don't forget to load the keys to your github account.

#### How to add ssh key to github account?

- Login to github account
- Click on the rancher on the top right (Settings)
  [image: github account settigns]
- Click on the `SSH keys`
  [image: ssh key section]
- Click on the `Add ssh key`
  [image: Add ssh key]
- Paste your key and save

And you all set to go :-)

Answer (score 0):

Create config file inside the **.ssh directory** with name **config**.

Then inside the config file write down these configurations. Change the **your-file-name** to your **SSH key file-name** and change the
**your-host-name** to your **preferred host-name**

```
Host <your-host-name>
 HostName github.com
 User git
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<your-file-name>
```

**The config file should be looking something like this after the edit.**

[image]

**Then we will clone the same old way using a modified URL**

```
$ git clone git@github-personal:GhostWolfRider/Angular-Admin-Dashboard.git
```

**Check out this medium article to know more >>**

**[Generate & Manage Multiple SSH Keys on a Single Device](https://medium.com/@krunalRajkotiya/generate-manage-multiple-ssh-keys-on-single-device-400d9b2c16c1)**

Let me know if you still have any questions.